# How remove an element from array with Redux ? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redux

i wanted to remove an element from an array but i'm not getting, my code is:

```js
const renderCount = state => {
  const peopleHtml = state.filteredPeople.map(person => {
    const personHtml = document.createElement('LI');
    const personName = document.createTextNode(person.name);
    const buttonDelete = document.createElement('Button');
    const textOfButtonDelete = document.createTextNode('Delete');

    buttonDelete.appendChild(textOfButtonDelete);

    personHtml.appendChild(personName);

    personHtml.appendChild(buttonDelete);

    buttonDelete.onclick = function() {
return {...state,filteredPeople : state.filteredPeople.filter( (item, index) => index !=="Jean")}
  }
    return personHtml;
  });

  resultado.innerHTML = '';
  peopleHtml.forEach(personHtml => resultado.appendChild(personHtml));
};

export default renderCount;
```

What the code makes?
He renders the elements of an array, 3 in 3. Each element of array have a button 'delete'and each time that i clicked that, a element get out off the screen.

The code and the button are: `buttonDelete.onclick....`.

Thanks and good afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right  way to do in reactjs. React believe on Virtual DOM. Your states values and HTML elements will be talking with each other and you do not need to use appendChild or removeChild to update them , just update the state value. Some thing like below

```
render()
    {
        return (
          <div>
             <ul>

             {this.state.filteredPeople.map(person => { =>
              <li>
               {person.name} 
               <button onClick={this.deleteme.bind(this,person.id)}>Delete</button>
             </li>
          )}

            </ul>

         </div>

        );
    }
deleteme(index){
     let initial_val = this.state.contents.slice();
     let obj_to_del= initial_val.find(person => person.id === id);
     initial_val.remove(obj_to_del);
   this.setState({people:initial_val});

}
```

Comment: If OP had indicated that they were using React, you'd be right (sort of—OP is asking about Redux and your answer is very non-Reduxy), but OP did not indicate that they are using React.